# How to target input using jQuery Validate plugin without using the name attribute?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, jquery-validate

I'm using the popular jQuery validation plugin: [Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

As many know, this plugin works great and is well thought through. However, I'm using an asp.net application which automatically generates the name attributes for all my input fields. Further, the names it generates seem to be invalid to use in the jquery plugin.

I'm wondering if there is another way to target input elements using this plugin, or if the name attribute is the only way.

```
    <script>
jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#form1').validate({
        debug: true;
        invalidHandler: function(e, validator) {
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            if (errors) {
                var message = errors == 1
                    ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted below'
                    : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields.  They have been highlighted below';
                $("div.error span").html(message);
                $("div.error").show();
            } else {
                $("div.error").hide();
            }
        },

            rules: {
                <%=firstName.UniqueID%>: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                },
                verify:{
                    required: true,
                    equalTo: "#password",
                }


            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

I tried replacing the name with a server side call of the property (shown in "firstName") which does properly call back the name. But the jquery doesn't work at that point, so I'm guessing the generated name is invalid since it has "$" in it.

Rendered:

```
    <script>

jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#form1').validate({

        debug: true;

        invalidHandler: function(e, validator) {

            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();

            if (errors) {

                var message = errors == 1

                    ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted below'

                    : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields.  They have been highlighted below';

                $("div.error span").html(message);

                $("div.error").show();

            } else {

                $("div.error").hide();

            }

        },



            rules: {

                ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBody$firstName: {

                    required: true,

                    minlength: 6,

                },

                email: {

                    required: true,

                    email: true,

                },

                password: {

                    required: true,

                    minlength: 6,

                },

                verify:{

                    required: true,

                    equalTo: "#password",

                }





            }

        });

    });



</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<label>Name</label>

<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBody$firstName" type="text" id="firstName" /><br />



<label>Email</label>

<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBody$ctl00" type="text" /><br />



<label>Password</label>

<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBody$password" type="text" id="password" /><br />



<label>Verify Password</label>

<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBody$verify" type="text" id="verify" /><br />



<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBody$submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
```

Comment: Why do you need to have names like those? Cant you change them to something valid?

Comment: asp.net automatically generates those names. I can't change them to anything else... Especially something without the $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs say any name with illegal JavaScript identifiers need to be wrapped in quotes when you set the rules options. Here's the link: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29

I'm not sure though, if it will work with a $ symbol, but it might be worth a try if you haven't already.

Comment: That worked! I still had to give the long auto-generated name, but at least it worked!

Comment: Yep, you have to use the generated name because asp.net renders them before the page even loads, so the browser sees the long names - thus jQuery does as well.